# Stack Spectrograms Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, spectrogram

I am trying to stack 2 spectrograms and I am not able to see the stacked spectrograms.
Here's my code:

```
Pxx1, freqs, bins, im = specgram(test_data, NFFT=NFFT, Fs=Fs, noverlap=900, cmap=cm.gist_heat)
Pxx2, freqs, bins, im = specgram(test_datb, NFFT=NFFT, Fs=Fs, noverlap=900, cmap=cm.gist_heat)
x = concatenate((Pxx1,Pxx2),axis=1)
ha = plt.subplot(111)
ha.pcolormesh(bins, freqs, x)
plt.show()
```

Errors I see:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "CreateDB.py", line 126, in <module>
    ha.pcolormesh(bins, freqs, 10 * np.log10(x))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes.py", line 7734, in pcolormesh
    X, Y, C = self._pcolorargs('pcolormesh', *args, allmatch=allmatch)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes.py", line 7376, in _pcolorargs
    C.shape, Nx, Ny, funcname))
TypeError: Dimensions of C (513, 1436) are incompatible with X (718) and/or Y (513); see help(pcolormesh)
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Try using `imshow` first instead of `pcolormesh` and see if you get at least correct stacking. By the way in `numpy` you can use `vstack` and `hstack`. You are stacking two matrices so the dimension of the resulting matrix is larger than length of `bins`. You'd need to create another axis with correct dimensions

Comment: I used `vstack` to stack the spectrograms but the axes are not correct. How do I correct the axes?

Comment: You need to make your `bins` or `freqs` whatever is correct axis accordingly to expansion of your matrix. Say you have matrices Z and Z2, both 10x20. And you have X which is size 10, and Y which is size 20. Now you stack Z and Z2 to get a matrix ZC=20x20, but your X is still size 10. So you need another 10 elements in your X. I would try `freq2=freq*2.0; freq=concatenate((freq,freq2), axis=?)`. Now you should have your `freq` axis having correct amount of elements. Then you need to figure out if this is what you want. But as I mentioned, the error comes from incorrect amount of elements.